# Need help to find a maths/ statistics function to best identify a record in a dataset

Tags: math, statistics, latitude-longitude

**Dataset Charactersitics**

- Lat/ lon coordinates are captured periodically (UTC date time column)
- Dataset is in Asceding Order

**Problem**

- Want to find out the place where most time was spent

[Dataset Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCPA1.png)

Problem described and smaple dataset prepared.

TAB Delimited sample dataset.

```
row_id  device_id   lat lon UTC AEST    meter_Diff_from_last_logrecord
840 SM-S908E    -37.8481875 145.0796565 2023-05-20 20:39:20 2023-05-21 06:39:20 0.377691197
841 SM-S908E    -37.84950872    145.0878352 2023-05-20 20:40:20 2023-05-21 06:40:20 0.732983785
842 SM-S908E    -37.8503321 145.0954142 2023-05-20 20:41:20 2023-05-21 06:41:20 0.671723112
843 SM-S908E    -37.85033269    145.097975  2023-05-20 20:42:20 2023-05-21 06:42:20 0.224840766
844 SM-S908E    -37.850337  145.0980465 2023-05-20 20:43:20 2023-05-21 06:43:20 0.006296937
845 SM-S908E    -37.8503373 145.0980528 2023-05-20 20:44:20 2023-05-21 06:44:20 0.000554153
846 SM-S908E    -37.85034461    145.0980678 2023-05-20 20:45:20 2023-05-21 06:45:20 0.001547657
847 SM-S908E    -37.8503557 145.0980373 2023-05-20 20:46:20 2023-05-21 06:46:20 0.002948224
848 SM-S908E    -37.8503362 145.0980213 2023-05-20 20:47:20 2023-05-21 06:47:20 0.002583612
849 SM-S908E    -37.8503555 145.0980018 2023-05-20 20:48:45 2023-05-21 06:48:45 0.002745352
850 SM-S908E    -37.8503327 145.0980702 2023-05-20 20:49:45 2023-05-21 06:49:45 0.006518804
851 SM-S908E    -37.8503386 145.0980573 2023-05-20 20:50:45 2023-05-21 06:50:45 0.001308919
852 SM-S908E    -37.8503326 145.0980506 2023-05-20 20:51:45 2023-05-21 06:51:45 0.00088948
853 SM-S908E    -37.8503921 145.097994  2023-05-20 20:52:45 2023-05-21 06:52:45 0.008274612
854 SM-S908E    -37.8503588 145.0980575 2023-05-20 20:53:45 2023-05-21 06:53:45 0.006692947
855 SM-S908E    -37.8503645 145.0980348 2023-05-20 20:54:45 2023-05-21 06:54:45 0.00209144
856 SM-S908E    -37.8503872 145.0980962 2023-05-20 20:55:45 2023-05-21 06:55:45 0.005952652
857 SM-S908E    -37.8503592 145.0980295 2023-05-20 20:56:45 2023-05-21 06:56:45 0.006632526
858 SM-S908E    -37.8503375 145.0980492 2023-05-20 20:57:45 2023-05-21 06:57:45 0.002968845
859 SM-S908E    -37.8503191 145.098025  2023-05-20 20:58:54 2023-05-21 06:58:54 0.002949712
860 SM-S908E    -37.8503373 145.098035  2023-05-20 21:00:18 2023-05-21 07:00:18 0.002206006
861 SM-S908E    -37.8503372 145.0980549 2023-05-20 21:01:18 2023-05-21 07:01:18 0.001747282
862 SM-S908E    -37.8503349 145.097917  2023-05-20 21:02:18 2023-05-21 07:02:18 0.012113136
863 SM-S908E    -37.85017734    145.0932457 2023-05-20 21:03:18 2023-05-21 07:03:18 0.410519898
864 SM-S908E    -37.84892137    145.082619  2023-05-20 21:04:18 2023-05-21 07:04:18 0.943444844
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please remember that this is [not a general help forum](/help/on-topic) and that asking for tool recommendations is one of the explicit reasons for a question to get closed. So instead, what did you already come up with, how did you implement that, and how did that implementation not work? And of course, remember to read ["how to ask a good question"](/help/how-to-ask) in order to make sure your [edit] to your post are in line with SO posting rules to keep the post from getting closed.